# Cron of magento module (Google trusted store) is not working

Tags: magento, module, cron

Magento cron is working fine for our site in all modules except one module. This module is Google trusted store. This problem has been reported by other magento users too.

I looked into cron_schedule table and there is no pending tasks of this module. When I manually inserted the cron tasks of this module into the cron_schedule table, this module exactly did what it was supposed to do. So, what could be the problem with this module for this cron job? Here is the config.xml. I guess once we fix this issue, the module is just fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento Enterprise Edition
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Magento Enterprise Edition License
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_EE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://www.magentocommerce.com/license/enterprise-edition
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_GoogleTrustedStore
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2012 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://www.magentocommerce.com/license/enterprise-edition
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_GoogleTrustedStore>
            <version>1.6.0.0</version>
        </Mage_GoogleTrustedStore>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <googletrustedstore>
                <class>Mage_GoogleTrustedStore_Helper</class>
            </googletrustedstore>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <googletrustedstore>
                <class>Mage_GoogleTrustedStore_Model</class>
            </googletrustedstore>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <googletrustedstore_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mage_GoogleTrustedStore</module>
                </setup>
            </googletrustedstore_setup>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <googletrustedstore>
                <class>Mage_GoogleTrustedStore_Block</class>
            </googletrustedstore>
        </blocks>
        <googletrustedstore>
            <google_group_email>mage-google-trusted-store-news@googlegroups.com</google_group_email>
            <order_cancellation_reasons>
                <BuyerCanceled>Buyer Canceled</BuyerCanceled>
                <MerchantCanceled>Merchant Canceled</MerchantCanceled>
                <DuplicateInvalid>Duplicate Invalid</DuplicateInvalid>
                <FraudFake>Fraud Fake</FraudFake>
            </order_cancellation_reasons>
            <ftp_host>uploads.google.com</ftp_host>
            <carriers>
                <main>
                    <ups>UPS</ups>
                    <fedex>FedEx</fedex>
                    <usps>USPS</usps>
                </main>
                <other>
                    <dhl>DHL</dhl>
                    <dhlint>DHL</dhlint>
                </other>
            </carriers>
        </googletrustedstore>
    </global>
    <default>
        <google>
            <trustedstore>
                <enabled>1</enabled>
                <default_order_cancellation_reason>BuyerCanceled</default_order_cancellation_reason>
                <estimated_ship_date>3</estimated_ship_date>
            </trustedstore>
        </google>
    </default>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <googletrustedstore>
                    <file>googletrustedstore.xml</file>
                </googletrustedstore>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <events>
            <checkout_multishipping_controller_success_action>
                <observers>
                    <googletrustedstore>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>googletrustedstore/observer</class>
                        <method>collectMultishippingOrderIds</method>
                    </googletrustedstore>
                </observers>
            </checkout_multishipping_controller_success_action>
        </events>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Mage_GoogleShopping>
                    <files>
                        <default>Mage_GoogleTrustedStore.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Mage_GoogleShopping>
            </modules>
        </translate>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <googletrustedstore>
                    <file>googletrustedstore.xml</file>
                </googletrustedstore>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <googletrustedstore>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>googletrustedstore/observer</class>
                        <method>addCancellationReasonToOrder</method>
                    </googletrustedstore>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_before>
            <sales_convert_order_to_quote>
                <observers>
                    <googletrustedstore>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>googletrustedstore/observer</class>
                        <method>addCancellationReasonToSession</method>
                    </googletrustedstore>
                </observers>
            </sales_convert_order_to_quote>
            <checkout_submit_all_after>
                <observers>
                    <googletrustedstore>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>googletrustedstore/observer</class>
                        <method>collectAdminOrderId</method>
                    </googletrustedstore>
                </observers>
            </checkout_submit_all_after>
            <controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_index>
                <observers>
                    <googletrustedstore>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>googletrustedstore/observer</class>
                        <method>addOrderGridBlocksRenderingObserver</method>
                    </googletrustedstore>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_adminhtml_sales_order_index>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <googletrustedstore_generate_feeds>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0/20 * * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>googletrustedstore/feeder::generateFeeds</model>
                </run>
            </googletrustedstore_generate_feeds>
            <googletrustedstore_upload_feeds>
                <schedule>
                    <cron_expr>0 2 * * *</cron_expr>
                </schedule>
                <run>
                    <model>googletrustedstore/feeder::uploadFeeds</model>
                </run>
            </googletrustedstore_upload_feeds>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Comment: I'm not sure wether the model is resolved. You could try to change the model to `Mage_GoogleTrustedStore_Model_Feeder`::yourMethod. Everything else looks fine in the cron config.

Comment: Thanks Fabian, Finally, i figured out that cron is fine. but it was not basically generating text files. Initially, the cron was set up for mid night and they were being deleted from cron_schedule table before I tried to see them. when i changed it to every 20 minutes schedule, i found that it's fine. So, the problem was in somewhere else. i'll try to figure that out and write that on module reviews so that it may help other people to troubleshoot or understand that.

Comment: The feeds are not generated and updated.  What is the issue and how to solve that?

Comment: i dont know much about it but make sure your cron is working and i am not sure you may try changing <cron_expr> too

Answer (score 0):

We patched the community edition version of Google Trusted Stores and have documented the exact modifications required over at http://www.dcjcooltools.com/blog/magento-extensions/the-nightmare-that-is-google-trusted-stores-for-magento/.

The particular problems we solved include the Cron Job not processing properly (interesting little bug if I may say so myself), feed files being deleted EVEN IF the upload process didn't work and lastly, the shipper names being set to Other rather than USPS, FedEx etc. etc.

Let me know if our solutions work for you!

Regards,
Evan

Comment: while i click manually generate & upload feeds in admin,it iswkg good.  But automatically cron is not wkg.  my feeder.php has  if (false === $result) {
                    $item['error_message'] =
                        Mage::helper('googletrustedstore')->__("Unable to upload '%s' to '%s' on server %s", $item['local'], $item['remote'], $host);
                    $exceptions[] = $item['error_message'];
                } else {
                    $uploadedFiles[] = $item['local'];
                    $fs->rm($item['local']);
                    $item['successfully'] = true;
                }